# Wizard of subsets

Tags: visual, geometry, combinatorics, optimization, sliding-blocks

**Can you change this**

[image: Initial_configuration]

**into this**

[image: Example_configuration]

**in three moves?**

**You are the wizard of subsets.  With only your mind, you can grab any subset of the 16 stone blocks and move them one unit in any direction (north, east, south, west).  However, you may not cause two stone blocks to occupy the same space.  (That's next-level wizardry!)**

**Let's solve this one together to see how it's done:**

[image: Example_solving_process]

**Now it's your turn.  Can you change this**

[image: Initial_configuration]

**into this**

[image: Goal_configuration]

**in three moves?**

Comment: Note to computation nerds:  Obviously, I wrote a computer program to search through the various configurations of these 16 stone blocks.  However, you may be pleased to know that my program does not contain a single array or matrix.  Each configuration is represented by a 64-bit binary integer and all the moves are done through bit manipulations on those integers.

Comment: I don't see three moves in the first example. What is a 'move'?

Comment: @ACD — A move means you grab any subset of the stone blocks (highlighted in white) and move them one unit north, east, south, or west.  In the example, move #1 is three stones slid north, move #2 is three stones slid south, and move #3 is eight stones slid west.

Comment: I like the concept, but given multiple different answers, the puzzle presented is too easy. The walk-through example seems better, though it also has more than one [solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMZ3y.png)

Comment: @DanielMathias — Thanks, Daniel.  There are a lot of really difficult problems posed on this site, so sometimes it's refreshing just to have a simple, easy, slightly non-intuitive problem for everyone to enjoy.  Nice alternate solution, by the way.

Comment: I wonder if it's even possible to create an example with only one solution. I'm also afraid that once you've got the hang of it solving any one of these will be trivial, although I'm curious if you can actually make more challenging ones

Comment: @Ivo — You're asking the same questions I've been asking myself since I started this project!

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to come up with a boring puzzle with a unique solution (up to the symmetry of either moving a subset or its complement in a different direction). If we start with a set where the maximum horizontal separation is $n$ and aim to reach one where the maximum separation is $m+n$ in $m$, all of the moves must be horizontal and there are many configurations where the intermediate subsets are uniquely determined.

Comment: @DanielS — Agreed.  You could just move a single stone 5 squares away and then ask, "Can you achieve this configuration in 5 moves?"  It's boring and obvious, but it is a demonstration of a puzzle with a unique solution (i.e., one and only one possible solution).

Comment: @SlowMagic well, moving just a single stone doesn't give a problem with a unique solution, since you can also move the rest of the stones to the left instead of that one stone to the right. But I guess we can assume that these are equivalent.

Comment: @justhalf — Ah, yes, I should have added DanielS's careful qualification "up to the symmetry of either moving a subset or its complement in [the opposite] direction".  So, I guess there is no configuration with unique solution!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something

> Label the blocks left to right; top to bottom `0-F`. Select the subset `A-F`; move it two spaces East and one space North.

> ```
>  #0 #1 #2 #3    1) # # # #      2) # # # #        3) # # # #
>  #4 #5 #6 #7       # # # #         # # # #           # # # # # #
>  #8 #9 #A #B       # #   # #       # #     # #       # # # # # #
>  #C #D #E #F         # # # #           # # # #
> ```

Comment: This is a great solution!  It is the most intuitive and comprehensible to humans, because it breaks off a single chunk and keeps that chunk intact as it moves it around.

Answer (score 16):

> ```
>  l l l l
>  l l r r
>  l u u r
>  u u u u
> ```

Move those marked `l` to the left, then the `r`s right and then the `u`s up.

> ```
> 1) l l l l      2) l l l l        3) l l l l
>    l l   r r       l l     r r       l l u u r r
>    l   u u r       l   u u   r       l u u u u r
>      u u u u         u u u u
> ```

Comment: Nice, clear solution!  Unfortunately, I have three correct answers, so I have to choose the one which was posted first.

Answer (score 15):

Very similar to @loopy-walt solution, but still OC :)

> [image: solution]

Comment: Outstanding!  This is the only solution which achieves the goal by moving 16 stones overall, which is the minimum predicted by my computer program.  Unfortunately, I have three correct answers, so I have to choose the one which was posted first.

Comment: @SlowMagic loopy's solution also moves 16 stones, and each stone only once.

Comment: @justhalf — I count 18 total stone moves:  step #1 involves 9 stone moves, step #2 involves 3 stone moves, and step #3 involves 6 stone moves.  (And the u's move twice.)

Comment: @SlowMagic step 1 only has 7 stones moving. And each stone only move once, including the u's.

Comment: @justhalf — Aha, the complement!!  You're right.

Comment: Well, the moved stones are bolded, haha, and it's also described by the letters. L stones move left, R stones move right, U stones move up (which is clearly written by loopy)